# How many 3 digit positive integers are divisible by 5?

Tags: probability

Q1: How many 3 digit positive integers are divisible by 5?

Since it should be divisble by 5 it must end it 5?so

9 * 10 * 1

Is that right? But shouldn't I check if it ends in 0 or 5?

q2: how many odd non repeating 3 digit positive integers are there? It should end it either 1,3,5,7,9

So 9*9*5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1: Recall that a number is divisible by $5$ if and only if its last digit is either a $0$ or a $5$. So we have:
$$
9\cdot10\cdot2 = 180
$$

---

Q2: Observe that the only possibilities for the last digit that will make the number odd are $1,3,5,7,9$. Once you pick this digit, there will be $9-1=8$ remaining possibilities for the first digit. Once you pick these two digits, there will be $10-2=8$ remaining possibilities for the second digit. This yields:
$$
8 \cdot 8 \cdot 5 = 320
$$

Comment: @ Adriano my teacher said the answer is 90

Comment: @MethodManX Never take the word of authority over logic. A "second" argument (the first in disguise): there are 900 3-digit numbers, and every fifth one is divisible by 5, starting with the first one, 100. 900/5 = 180.

Comment: @MethodManX well, it's not

Comment: @ Adriano what about 7 isn't that odd

Comment: @MethodManX Ah okay, I thought the question stated that the last digit must end in either a $1,3,5,6,$or $9$. I guess you just made a typo. I've changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: @adriano thank you I marked ur answer as the check mark

Answer (score 1):

Another way of thinking about it is that we are looking at the numbers $5\cdot 20, 5\cdot 21, 5\cdot 22, 5\cdot 23$, and so on to $5\cdot 199$. There are therefore $199-20+1$ such numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You are right in thinking that the last digit can be either 0 or 5,
and there are 9 choices for the first digit and 10 for the second.